# Accessing user defined variables passed in from xcodebuild command line

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, xctest

I am running my `xctests` using xcodebuild and need to pass in some `environment variables`.
In the example below `ACCOUNT_ID` and `HOST_URL`.

I tried passing in the variables as both environment variable and accessing them from the test using `getenv ("ACCOUNT_ID")`
`xcodebuild -project CalculatorTestClient.xcodeproj -scheme CalculatorTestClient -destination '%s' ACCOUNT_ID=%s HOST_URL=%s test"`

And passing them in as `user defaults` and accessing them using `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"HOST_URL"];`
`xcodebuild -project CalculatorTestClient.xcodeproj -scheme CalculatorTestClient -destination '%s' ACCOUNT_ID=%s HOST_URL=%s test"`

Neither approach worked for me.
What is easiest way to pass user defined variables from commandline?

Comment: It seems not to be easy. Have a look here: http://blog.manbolo.com/2013/05/17/passing-user-variable-to-xcodebuild

Answer (score 58):

Similar to @Paul Young I was able to get this to work, with a couple of modifications to the Scheme. Here's my solution:

For the Scheme in Xcode (Xcode > Your Scheme > Edit Scheme > Test > Arguments tab > Environment Variables):

| Name | Value |
| --- | --- |
| ACCOUNT_ID | `$(ACCOUNT_ID)` |
| HOST_URL | `$(HOST_URL)` |

In Code (Swift 3):

```
let accountID = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["ACCOUNT_ID"]!
let hostURL = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["HOST_URL"]!
```

On the command line:

```
$ xcodebuild -project YourProject.xcodeproj \
-scheme "Your Scheme" \
-sdk iphonesimulator \
-destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 7,OS=10.2' \
-derivedDataPath './output' \
ACCOUNT_ID='An Account ID' \
HOST_URL='www.hosturl.com' \
test
```

For iOS, make sure to do modify the scheme with the following:

1. Uncheck the `Use the Run action's arguments and environment variables`
2. Change the drop down "Expand Variables Based On" to the
   Test target in the Test scheme.

Comment: Does this work for OSX only too? I would appreciate a working solution for iOS.

Comment: My solution is for iOS. This is how I pass in variables to my iOS UI tests

Comment: I have so much love for you right now. It took me a while to find this. Thanks! Exactly what I needed.

Comment: this works. this should be accepted answer @wherewouldibe

Comment: I have not been able to get this to work for iOS. Is ends up just putting "$(ACCOUNT_ID) into the value instead of the passed in value

Comment: @dadougster I had the same issue because I was running test-without-building but if you build first then run the test - it works

Comment: might help to specifically call out that you need to set the environment variable for the Scheme > Test .. not Scheme > Run (which is displayed by default) .. then it will be picked up.

Comment: @dadougster I could make it work to get the environment variable when uncheck the "Use the Run action's arguments and environment variables" as well ad change the drop down "Expand Variables Based On" to the UITest target in the Test scheme.

Comment: @BrunoBieri 's comment make sense, this answer should be accepted.

Comment: I had to use a different name when specifying the var in the xcode scheme: `ACCOUNT_ID` = `$(ACCNT_ID)`. Not happy about it, though

Answer (score 7):

What I did for my case is I used the `xcodebuild build-for-testing` command and create the `xctestrun` file then using `xcodebuild test-without-building` to run the test . in this case you can change the `xctestrun` file which has the environment variables in its plist before running your test .

so you need to run a script by using `PlistBuddy` to change your plist environment keys . for example to add a key :

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "add :APPNAME-TARGETNAME:EnvironmentVariables:KEYNAME string 'VALUE'" "(Path to XCTestRun file)"
```

Comment: Quite like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50004139

Answer (score 2):

So far I've only been able to get this approach to work:

```
$ ACCOUNT_ID=foo HOST_URL=bar xcodebuild -project CalculatorTestClient.xcodeproj -scheme CalculatorTestClient clean test
```

and accessed them via:

```
NSDictionary *environment = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment];
NSString *accountID = [environment objectForKey:@"ACCOUNT_ID"];
NSString *hostUrl = [environment objectForKey:@"HOST_URL"];
```

Comment: Just noticed that this only works for me when targeting OS X, not iOS.

Comment: Yes, my comment notes that it only worked for me when targeting OS X, not iOS.